# How to populate a value based on an element in XSL 1.0

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0, jdeveloper

My source sample XML is as below

```
<QuoteData>
    <Components>
        <Component  ServiceOfferingId="XX"  StartDate="07/03/2016"  EndDate="12/31/9999"  SerialOrderNbr="xx"  StopReasonCode=""  IsBundle="N">
            <ServiceItem  ItemType="xx"  Type="2072"  ModelFeature="24E"  ProductId="2072 24E"  SerialOrderNbr="xx"  Quantity="1"  StartDate="07/03/2016"  EndDate="12/31/9999"  CustomerId="xx"  ServiceLevelId="xx"/>
        </Component>
        <Component  ServiceOfferingId="yy"  StartDate="07/03/2016"  EndDate="12/31/9999"  SerialOrderNbr="yy"  StopReasonCode=""  IsBundle="N">
            <ServiceItem  ItemType="yy"  Type="2072"  ModelFeature="24C"  ProductId="2072 24C"  SerialOrderNbr="yy"  Quantity="1"  StartDate="07/03/2016"  EndDate="12/31/9999"  CustomerId="yy"  ServiceLevelId="yy"/>
            <ServiceItem  ItemType="zz"  Type="2072"  ModelFeature="24E"  ProductId="2072 24E"  SerialOrderNbr="zz"  Quantity="1"  StartDate="07/03/2016"  EndDate="12/31/9999"  CustomerId="zz"  ServiceLevelId="zz"/>
        </Component>
    </Components>
    <Descriptions>
        <ProductDescription  Id="2072 24E"  Description="Customer EXPANSION"/>
        <ProductDescription  Id="2072 24C"  Description="Customer CONTROL"/>
    </Descriptions>
</QuoteData>
```

As per requirement each ServiceItem should be converted into a Line. So, in the above case, 3 lines shoule be created.
In the Target, I should be able to populate  Product Description based on the Product ID value. Currently I am unable to do that using XSL 1.0

Expected target XML should be like below:

```
<Payload>
    <Header></Header>
    <Line>
        <SerialOrderNbr>xx</SerialOrderNbr>
        <ModelFeature>24E</ModelFeature>
        <ProductId>2072 24E</ProductId>
        <ProductDescription>Customer EXPANSION</ProductDescription>
    </Line>  
    <Line>
        <SerialOrderNbr>xx</SerialOrderNbr>
        <ModelFeature>24C</ModelFeature>
        <ProductId>2072 24C</ProductId>
        <ProductDescription>Customer CONTROL</ProductDescription>
    </Line>
    <Line>
        <SerialOrderNbr>xx</SerialOrderNbr>
        <ModelFeature>24E</ModelFeature>
        <ProductId>2072 24E</ProductId>
        <ProductDescription>Customer EXPANSION</ProductDescription>
    </Line>
</Payload>
```

I tried using different functions to populate the target description, but I am either getting the first Description value in all the lines or no value at all is being populated. I am able to achieve the required functionality using a while loop and assign activity in Jdev 11g.

How can I do this in XSLT?

Comment: Can you edit your question to show the XSLT you have currently tried? Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the following stylesheet is easily possible:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
  <xsl:output method="xml" /> 
  <xsl:template match="/QuoteData">
    <Payload>
      <xsl:for-each select="//ServiceItem">
        <line>
          <SerialOrderNbr><xsl:value-of select="@SerialOrderNbr" /></SerialOrderNbr>
          <ModelFeature><xsl:value-of select="@ModelFeature" /></ModelFeature>
          <ProductId><xsl:value-of select="@ProductId" /></ProductId>
          <ProductDescription><xsl:value-of select="//ProductDescription[@Id = current()/@ProductId]/@Description" /></ProductDescription>
        </line>
      </xsl:for-each>
    </Payload>
  </xsl:template>    
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Its output is:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<Payload>
    <line>
        <SerialOrderNbr>xx</SerialOrderNbr>
        <ModelFeature>24E</ModelFeature>
        <ProductId>2072 24E</ProductId>
        <ProductDescription>Customer EXPANSION</ProductDescription>
    </line>
    <line>
        <SerialOrderNbr>yy</SerialOrderNbr>
        <ModelFeature>24C</ModelFeature>
        <ProductId>2072 24C</ProductId>
        <ProductDescription>Customer CONTROL</ProductDescription>
    </line>
    <line>
        <SerialOrderNbr>zz</SerialOrderNbr>
        <ModelFeature>24E</ModelFeature>
        <ProductId>2072 24E</ProductId>
        <ProductDescription>Customer EXPANSION</ProductDescription>
    </line>
</Payload>
```

This is not exactly what you claimed to expect as output, because your version of the desired output seems to be erroneous. In your output version all `SerialOrderNbr`s have 'xx' as value, but in your source XML they are different.

Comment: Thank you soo much....it works like a charm!!. And sorry for the typo in SerialOrderNbr. Do you have any link where i can find these kind of different XSL functions. Sincerely appreciate your response. And thanks a ton again.

Comment: @Mohan P: A good start is [the reference at w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/xsl_w3celementref.asp). It's not perfect, but very vivid.